# Class variables shared between 2 async tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, discord.net

I am trying to make a Discord.Net bot for my Discord Server. I would like the Bot to share data between commands, but currently because of the nature of the async tasks, the class variables are reset to null as a new instance is created on each task. I was wondering how other Discord Bots handle this problem.

I know I am able to save the values to a file/DB but I was hoping to use something simpler to allow for multiple concurrent commands.

```
using Discord.Commands;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UsefulDiscordBot.Modules
{
    public class Foo : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        string test;

        [Command("initializeString")]
        public async Task initializeString()
        {
            test = "Initialized";
        }

        [Command("addToString")]
        public async Task addToString([Remainder]string s)
        {
            test += s;
        }

        [Command("printString")]
        public async Task printString()
        {
            await ReplyAsync(test);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with a `static` variable?

Comment: You need to use a single instance of Foo. That way the string test variable will be shared accross calls.  Also if you want to share fields between async calls you will need to use some syncronization mechanism like a lock.

Answer (score 1):

Command modules in Discord.Net are Transient (they are spawned when required and disposed of once executed). That said, the general best practice (when building a bot with Discord.Net) for what you wish to achieve is to use a `Service` - a Class to store your data external to the command module.

You can read up on how to do this via the [Discord.Net documentation](https://discordnet.dev/faq/basics/dependency-injection.html#what-is-a-service-why-does-my-module-not-hold-any-data-after-execution). There's a section in the FAQ (linked) specifically for this. Hope it helps.